# How to inject variables from Android Application

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I defined a variable in `Application`, I need to inject it into `WorkViewModal`.

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidApp
class SageApplication : Application() {
  val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
}
```

but I can't do this, because `ApplicationContext` does not have my custom attribute `applicationScope`.

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class WorkViewModel @Inject constructor(
  @ApplicationContext private val applicationContext: ApplicationContext
) : ViewModel() {
```

I also can't use `@Provides` to provide an instance of `SageApplication`. It also needs to provide `SageApplication`, but I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do.

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class ApplicationModule {
  @Provides
  fun provideApplicationScope(@ApplicationContext application: SageApplication) = application.applicationScope
}
```

I want to inject `applicationScope` into `ViewModel` like this:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class WorkViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope
) : ViewModel()
```

what should I do?

Comment: You will be able to pass ApplicationContext if you need but you won't be able to pass CoroutineScope like you have done and if you want to pass CoroutineScope then you will need to create a separate module and define function there with @Provides annotation and from there you can return the CoroutineScope variable.

Comment: @KaranMehta  Is your solution the same as `Thilanka Ishara Gunathilake`  's answer?

Comment: What do you need in the Viewmodel? applicationContext or couroutineScope?

Comment: @KaranMehta I need `CouroutineScope`. I mean, the answer of `Thilanka Ishara Gunathilake` solved my problem, do you have any other better solution?

Comment: @ThilankaIsharaGunathilake You seem to have deleted your answer, what happened?